# rtl8812au driver Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, tp-link

I've a TP-Link Archer T2U Nano in my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. At first int doesn't even recognize it but after I install the driver it starts working. The issue is that it only works well in 5GHz and when I connect to a 2.4GHz Wifi network it connects but it's too slow and webpages constantly stop responding. Seems to be an issue with the driver. I've installed the drived by the following method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms

git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [gordboy's RTL8812au-5.9.3.2 driver](https://github.com/gordboy)?  Works for me.